# Rearranging indicies inside Java List

Tags: java, list, indexing

Imagine having a List in Java < 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 > specified by indices (1-5).

If I want to move the item on index 2 (2) to index 4 and rearrange the List to < 1, 3, 4, 2, 5 >.

Is there an easy way/collection framework to implement this? LinkedList seems like a solution.

Comment: Sets are not intended for that purpose. Values are not supposed to be indexed. Even if it would technically be possible with a messy code, it would not be advisable to do so.

Comment: `int i = list.get(2); list.set(2, list.get(4)); list.set(4, i)`

Comment: Sets do not have orders, unless you are relying on a specific implementation (like a LinkedHashSet), so there is no notion of indexing in a set. Lists, from the other side, are ordered and depending your requirements for performance you can choose between different implementations.

Comment: Sets have no ordering in java

Comment: Yes, LinkedLists are ordered, so you can use a LinkedList. But that's nothing to do with sets.

Comment: Sorry, meant having a List

Comment: FYI: Java is 0-indexed, making your first sentence an incorrect statement. So a list containing the items `[1,2,3,4,5]` will have the indices `[0,1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: I know its 0-indexed, but it is required using a sortIndex from 1 - infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't want to swap 2 items but rather remove an item and then insert it later you can use this:

```
public static <T> void move(List<T> list, int i, int j) {
    list.add(j, list.remove(i));
}
```

This makes use of the methods `List.add(int, T)` which inserts an item into the list at a specific index and `List.remove(int)` which removes the element at the given index and returns it.

Another way would be to use `Collections.rotate()` and `List.sublist()`:

```
 public static <T> void move(List<T> list, int i, int j) {
    Collections.rotate(list.sublist(i, j), -1);
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I don't need it to be swapped, rather rearranged. In your example assigning the Index 2 (= 3) to index 4 the list should look like:  [1, 2, 4 , 5 ,3]

Answer (score 5):

use [Collections::swap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap(java.util.List,%20int,%20int)) method

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4));
Collections.swap(list, 1,3);    // will swap the elements at the specified positions
```

If you want just move one the element to some position then try:

```
list.add(2, list.remove(0));    // move the item from index 0 to index 2
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues you're facing is that by using a Set, for practical purposes, you're limiting yourself either to an unordered HashSet or a sort-ordered TreeSet. When you talk about changing the indexing, you are implicitly talking about a different type of collection. And yes, a List would be a good choice for a collection where *you* specify the order.

Also, keep in mind that indexing in Java is 0-based, so once you have a List on the order you want, like  List< 1, 3, 4, 2, 5>, 1 is in index 0, 2 will be in index 3, etc.